# Wie sagt man "Not in a million years!" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, english-to-german, idiom

Willst du meine Freundin sein? - Nicht in einer Million Jahren!

Wie sagt man *Not in a million years* auf Deutsch?

Comment: PMF has pointed out the most straightforward translation which is very well suited for practical use. However, thekeyofgb's answer with "*Nie im Leben*" probably is even a better choice to say.

Comment: Ich meine, dass man sich hierzulande meist mit 1000 Jahren begnügt, selbt das sog. Reich. PMFs Antwort ist ansonsten richtig, auch wenn man andere Ausdrücke häufiger verwendet wie thekeyofgbs "Nie im Leben", "niemals". Kaum benutzt: "Nicht bevor die Hölle zufriert".

Comment: Though it does not fit in this context, sometimes “Nur über meine Leiche.” (Over my dead body) works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is more common:

> Nie im Leben

Comment: other possibilities would be *Da kannst du lang' drauf warten.* oder *Träum weiter!*

Comment: auch "Im Leben nicht."

Comment: Or *Nie und nimmer!*

Comment: Wenn Weihnachten und Ostern auf einen Tag fallen.

Comment: Oder _am Sankt Nimmerleinstag_. Doch das klingt etwas altmodisch.

Comment: *Und wovon träumst du nachts?*

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent idiomatic expression is "Keinesfalls." (literally, "In no case.")

Ein idiomatisches Äquivalent auf Deutsch ist "Keinesfalls." (wörtlich, "In no case.")

Answer (score 0):

Mir kommt noch dies in den Sinn:

> Für kein Geld der Welt.
>
> Für nichts auf der Welt.
>
> Soviel kannst du mir nicht bezahlen als dass ich...

Comment: Willkommen auf German.SE. Vorschlag zur Verbesserung der Antwort: streichen von "gute antworten,". Etwas Struktur, z.B. mit Anstrichen zur besseren Sichtbarkeit, wo welches Beispiel aufhört.

Comment: Das wären Stilblüten. Die Hyperbeln passen schon deshalb nicht zur beschriebenen Situation, weil Freundschaften normalerweise nicht gegen Geld eingegangen werden.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: die Vorschläge passen aber zu Überschrift, wenn man den Text der Frage nur als Beispiel betrachtet. Das könnte die Antwort deutlicher machen.